# angular2 use jwt_decode library

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt, angular2-services

Basically my issue is using jwt_decode in angular2-webpack-starter project.
I also created the issue in github. 
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/755#issuecomment-230529931

It is about using .js library in angular2 typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in github.
I need to update the file again.
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/755